# React client receives two connections using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am developing a simple app with SocketIO and I am encountering this problem. In the server I have the following code:

```js
const httpServer = require('http').createServer();
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const port = process.env.PORT_WS || 5001;
const io = socketIO(httpServer, { cors: { origin: '*' } });
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Connected to socket');
  socket.on('join-room', () => {
    console.log('joined room')
  });
});

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on the port ${port}`);
});
```

In the client I have the following code:

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export default class SocketConnection {

  constructor() {
    this.initializeSocketConnection();
    this.initializeSocketEvents();
  }

  initializeSocketConnection() {
    console.log('I am here');
    this.socket = io('ws://localhost:5001');
  }

  initializeSocketEvents() {
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Socket connected');
    });
  }
}
```

I get in the console two `Socket connected` messages.

This is not a re-render issue because the `I am here` message is logged only once.

I am using `socket.io` version `4.0.1` both in the client and in the backend.

Comment: Hi, how many times your are see'ing from server console that says 'Connected to socket'?

Comment: @halilcakar I posted my own answer. It was because I was in strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is happening because, in React Strict Mode, constructors are called two times. React seems to hide this. As the `console.log('Socket connected');` is inside an "on" event, React has no way to "hide" this. Thus, `'I am here'` is going to be shown once but `'Socket connected'` is going to be shown twice.